# Magento 2 - Crud generator

Tags: magento2, discussion

Like Laravel and Yii, do Magento 2 has CRUD generator?

There would a lot of efforts save if Magento 2 has it's own CRUD generator, so that everytime I will create a new module related to a table I don't want to create all the files manually, there should be a crud generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any kind of command that will generate your module or generate CRUD.

But you can use online tools to generate your module.

I personally use SilkSoftware module generator:
https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php

But Mage2Gen is also a good module generator, you can also use that
https://mage2gen.com/

Magen plaza module generator (Didn't personally use it)
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-module-creator.html

Just search on google "magento 2 module generator" and you will find all these

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Comment: I can confirm that the mageplazza links through to [UltimateModuleCreator](https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc) and this will create the _module, model and CRUD **all in one**_.  It is fantastic.  There is one issue I find is that all the names of the modules and entities need to be single words because they are used to generate table names.  Acronyms like CRUD are also an issue... it creates errors in the table names and fails to `setup:upgrade`.  Avoid that and it's fantastic as I said :)

Comment: @Barry thanks for sharing the UMC.. you save me a lot of time.